# Haskell: List to Rose Tree

Tags: list, haskell, tree, higher-order-functions

Consider the following type to represent Rose trees:

```
data RTree a = No a [RTree a]
```

Consider the function

```
tolist a = tolistAux 1 a
     where tolistAux n (No x l) = (x,n) : (concat (map (tolistAux (n+1)) l))
```

I need to define the inverse of the first function: `unlist :: [(a,Int)] -> RTree a`

such that `unlist (tolist a) = a`

Comment: This is so similar to your previous question, I believe you will learn more by doing this step of your assignment without extra input. Please think hard about your previous question, and why your instructor asked it immediately before this one.

Comment: @enoughreptocomment I put up a possible solution. How could I readapt the solution to my previous question here? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I found.

I realized that if in (a,b), b==1 then I create a No a (...)
Thus, I have a list and isolate this list into several lists that start with (a,1) by first subtracting 1 to b.
Then, I create the tree using recursion (e,g a map function):

```
unlist ((x,1):t) = No x l3
where l1 = map (\(a,b) -> (a,b-1)) t
  l2 = isolate1 l1
  l3 = map unlist l2

isolate1 :: [(a,b)]->[[(a,b)]] --note that the result of isolate1 is a list of lists of pairs
isolate1 [] = []
isolate [x]=[[x]]
isolate1 ((a,b):t) = let (x:xs):ys = isolate1 t  
                     in |b==1 = ((a,b):x:xs):ys
                        |otherwise = [(a,b)]:(x:xs):ys
```

Glad to see more solutions :)